# Option Arrow keys for moving cursor by word for file paths in terminal (macOS Catalina) in zsh

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh

I've recently updated my terminal shell to zsh on Mac OS Catalina and have found one difference from before, in which I'd prefer the previous behavior.  When working in Terminal, using option arrows would move my cursor forward or backwards by one word each time.  For file paths, it would move it by one directory at a time in my file path.  With my update, I now see that when using this key combination with file paths in my command, instead of going directory by directory, it treats the entire file path as a single word.  As I often change just parts of my file path for some repeated commands, I would like to know if anyone else had experienced this or found a workaround.

Comment: My workaround was to go back to bash.  It seems unconscionable to me that Apple would have forced such a fundamental change on me without my permission.  Make zsh an option?  Sure.  Make it easy, even.  But change my current setting?   No way.  Maybe others don't live in the command line, like I do.

Comment: I wasn't aware that existing settings were changed, only that `zsh` would be the default shell for new accounts.

Comment: You will probably have better luck asking this on unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com. It's not really a programming question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try those sites as well.